# MYSQL getting data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, right-join

I am trying to find the drinker and total amount of money spent on drinks for all drinkers in February 2020. I also need to include drinkers who haven't ordered a drink in this period.

Here are the three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DRINKERS ( /* All drinkers */
DRINKER VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DRINKERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (DRINKER)); 

CREATE TABLE SERVES(    /* Pubs serve drinks */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
PRICE       DECIMAL(5,2)    NOT NULL,   /* Drink price  */
    CONSTRAINT SERVES_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(PUB, DRINK),
        CONSTRAINT SERVES_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB) 
        REFERENCES LOCATED(PUB),
    CONSTRAINT SERVES_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINK)
        REFERENCES ALLDRINKS(DRINK)  );

CREATE TABLE ORDERS(    /* Drinkers visit pubs and consumes drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
ODATE       DATE        NOT NULL,   /* Order date   */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
DRINK_NO    DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL,   /* A sequence number of a drink */
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, PUB, ODATE, DRINK, DRINK_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB, DRINK) REFERENCES SERVES(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)   );
```

Here is my statement so far:

```
SELECT ORDERS.DRINKER, SUM(SERVES.PRICE)
FROM ORDERS
LEFT JOIN SERVES ON ORDERS.DRINKER = SERVES.PRICE
GROUP BY ORDERS.DRINKER;
```

I am very new to SQL, I know that there are a number of mistakes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join  as

```
SELECT D.DRINKER , SUM(ifnull(S.PRICE,0))
FROM DRINKERS D
LEFT JOIN ORDERS O ON D.DRINKER  = O.DRINKER    
INNER JOIN  SERVES S ON O.PDB = S.PUB
    AND S.DRINK = O.DRINK
GROUP BY D.DRINKER;
```

and if you need  only february

```
SELECT D.DRINKER , SUM(ifnull(S.PRICE,0))
FROM DRINKERS D
LEFT JOIN ORDERS O ON D.DRINKER  = O.DRINKER    
    AND year(O.ODATE) = 2020 AND month(O.ODATE) = 2
INNER JOIN  SERVES S ON O.PDB = S.PUB
    AND S.DRINK = O.DRINK

GROUP BY D.DRINKER;
```

Comment: we'd need an outer join to get drinkers who don't have an order ...

Comment: Does that work? Your inner join on `serves` requires to be `orders` in the row, so your outer join becomes an inner join. You would have to make the `serves` join an outer join, too, to make the outer join work, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Noods I am confused. You explicitly mentioned that you need data for only February 2020 and this solution doesn't have `where` clause for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use simple `inner join` and `left join` along with `month()` and `year()` functions. You'll get result for all drinker regardless if they ordered a drink or not. So you'll have result for non-drinkers during February.

```
select a.drinker,sum(c.price)
from drinkers a left join orders b on a.drinker = b.drinker
join serves c on b.pub = c.pub and b.drink = c.drink
where month(b.odate) = 'February' and year(b.odate) = 2020
group by a.drinker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all `DRINKERS`, whether they've ordered or not, you'll want to start with that table. Then `LEFT JOIN` to the `ORDERS` table, to get the orders for those who have some.

This is a guess, but it appears from the column `DRINK_NO` that there is one row in `ORDERS` per drink served. Since you only want total drinks for this query, I would suggest using a sub-query of that table, rather than joining to the full table. Since this table includes the `ODATE` data, you can filter your results here in the sub-query. You could also filter with a `WHERE` clause on the outer query, but it will be more efficient doing it here.

```
SELECT
  DRINKER,
  PUB,
  DRINK,
  COUNT(DRINK_NO) AS QUANTITY 
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY
  DRINKER,
  PUB,
  DRINK
WHERE
  MONTH(ODATE) = 2 AND YEAR(ODATE) = 2020
```

Finally, `INNER JOIN` your sub-query to `SERVES` in order to get the pricing information.

The fully constructed query should be close to this:

```
SELECT
  d.DRINKER,
  SUM(o.PRICE * o.QUANTITY) AS TotalSpent
FROM
  DRINKERS AS d
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        DRINKER,
        PUB,
        DRINK,
        COUNT(DRINK_NO) AS QUANTITY
      FROM ORDERS
      GROUP BY
        DRINKER,
        PUB,
        DRINK
      WHERE
        MONTH(ODATE) = 2 AND YEAR(ODATE) = 2020
    ) AS o
    ON o.DRINKER = d.DRINKER
  INNER JOIN SERVES AS s
    ON o.PUB = s.PUB
    AND o.DRINK = s.DRINK
GROUP BY
  d.DRINKER;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of query patterns that will return a result that satisfies the specification. Here's one example:

```
SELECT d.drinker               AS drinker
     , IFNULL(SUM(s.price),0)  AS tot_feb_prices
  FROM `DRINKERS` d
    -- 
  LEFT
  JOIN `ORDERS` o
    ON o.drinker  = p.drinker
   AND o.odate   >= '2020-02-01' 
   AND o.odate    < '2020-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    --
  LEFT
  JOIN `SERVES` s
    ON s.pub   = o.pub
   AND s.drink = o.drink
    --
 GROUP
    BY d.drinker
 ORDER
    BY d.drinker
```

---

another alternative is to use a correlated subquery in the select list (the subquery must return a scalar... only one column, and at most one row.)

```
SELECT d.drinker
    --
     , ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.price),0)
           FROM `ORDERS` o
           JOIN `SERVES` s
             ON s.pub   = o.pub
            AND s.drink = o.drink
          WHERE o.drinker  = p.drinker
            AND o.odate   >= '2020-02-01' 
            AND o.odate    < '2020-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
       ) AS tot_feb_prices
    --
  FROM `DRINKERS` d
 ORDER BY d.drinker
```